# Throwing Exceptions w/ `forever`?

Tags: haskell

Looking at `forever`:

```
λ: import Control.Monad
λ: :t forever
forever :: Monad m => m a -> m b
```

Why does `forever $ Just 42` throw an exception after a few seconds?

```
λ: forever $ Just 42
*** Exception: <<loop>>
```

Yet `forever $ return 4` does not (at least after a few seconds)?

```
λ: forever $ return 4
^C^C^C^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ghci
```

Comment: Just to be clear: semantically, exceptions and infinite loops are not distinguishable, as they are both given the bottom denotation. So semantically, there is *no* discrepancy here between `forever (return 0) :: Maybe ()` and `forever (return 0) :: IO ()`.

Comment: GHC uses things called "grey holes" to deal with lazy values in a concurrent context. To avoid duplicating a ton of code, it also uses them in the single-threaded runtime, where for debugging purposes they're morphed into "black holes" that sometimes let you know you're in an infinite loop. It has to be just the right sort of infinite loop, and it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

To not go into the details of implementation (which I'm not entirely familiar with), I'll instead explain why this behavior is desirable and where it comes from.

`forever` is defined as

```
forever x = do
    x
    forever x
```

Which is equivalent to

```
forever x = x >> forever x
```

So if we look at

```
fr x = forever (return x)
```

We have

```
fr x = forever (return x)
     = return x >> forever (return x)
     = return x >>= \_ -> fr x
     = (\_ -> fr x) x
     = fr x
```

So, basically, `fr x` is an infinite loop.

Now in Haskell, an infinite loop and an error are identical. Here is one possible implementation of `error`:

```
error s = error s
```

Now, GHC chooses to distinguish between these two types of loops.

An infinite loop in pure code is an error. We didn't intend to enter one, generally, and we are looking for a value, not a side effect. therefore, in `Maybe` an infinite loop ends in an error.

However, infinite loops in effectful code are common! The code could be waiting for something else to happen on a machine, or user input, or something.

So in`IO` we have an actual infinite loop, one which means something.